# Optimize mysql multiple updates

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, sql-update, innodb

I am trying to optimize updates of a single column for more than 3M rows.
Column data are stored in a pandas dataframe  (row sql index is known)
Currently the code I am using is (using sqlalchemy for connection)

```
    conn = getConnection(db).connect()
    trans = conn.begin()
    try:
        i=0
        for index, row in data.iterrows():
            if not np.isnan(row[colName]):
                i+=1
                sql = 'update data set `{0}`= {1} where data_id={2};'.format(colName, row[colName], index)
                conn.execute(sql)
            if i>10000:
                i = 0
                trans.commit()
                trans = conn.begin()
        trans.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        trans.rollback()
    conn.close()
```

Here are some innodb variables

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 402653184
innodb_io_capacity = 200
```

How this code can be optimized since currently I meet times that a rollback is trigerred.

Comment: You should look at a solution using bulk-insert in a temporary table and after that executing an update statement.

Comment: @JeroenHeier, can you please elaborate, I can use pandas DataFrame.to_sql to bulk insert into tmp table and then?

Comment: Execute an update statement joining between tmp and data using data_id as key?

Answer (score 0):

10K is an unreasonably large chunk.

`UPDATE` does a number of things

1. Parse the statement and decide on a query plan.
2. Prepare to rollback (make a copy of the row as it was before the update);
3. Update the row (read, modify, write);
4. Add any secondary index changes to the Change Buffer, which will eventually need lead to writes to the index(es).

I recommend no more than 1000 per clump (ie, per `COMMIT`).  The efficiency difference (assuming no timeout) between 1000 and 10000 is probably less than 1%.

The current code does all 4 steps for each iteration.

The suggestion of building a tmp table, then using a multi-table `UPDATE` to do the update *may or may not* be faster:

- Need to `CREATE`, etc, the temp table (once/clump)
- Insert a clump's worth or rows.  This can (and should) be optimized into a single `INSERT` statement with lots of rows.  (Again, I recommend no more than 1000.)  If this is a 'transactional' table type, then there are `ROLLBACK` considerations here, too.
- You save #1 (the parse), but still have to do #2-4 for each row updated.

In any case, it is a lot more code.  Changing 10000 to 1000 is the simple and effective answer to your question.